# Point void-pointer to char-pointer

Tags: c

I have two pointers. A `char` pointer with the string "test", and a `void` pointer.
I'm trying to have `pointer` point to the address of `string`.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    void *pointer = NULL;
    char *string = "test";
    *(char*)pointer = &string;

    printf("The string address: %p\n", string);
    printf("The string: %s\n", string);
    printf("The pointer address: %p\n", pointer);
    printf("The pointer points to: %p", *(char*)pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

When I set `pointer` to be equal to the address of `string` on line 6 I get `makes integer from pointer without a cast`. How can I do this?

Edit:
I was printing the wrong addresses. I meant for the printf lines to look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    void *pointer = NULL;
    char *string = "test";
    pointer = &string;

    printf("The string address: %p\n", &string);
    printf("The string: %s\n", string);
    printf("The pointer address: %p\n", &pointer);
    printf("The pointer points to: %p", pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

It now properly prints out this:

> The string address: 0028FF18 
> The string: test 
> The pointer address:
>   0028FF1C 
> The pointer points to: 0028FF18

So `string` and `pointer` are separate pointers and `pointer` points to `string`.

Comment: The address of `string` is not an object, and thus cannot be addressed.

Comment: a simple and elegant, `pointer = string` will do.

Comment: `pointer = string` changes the location of pointer though. I want `pointer` to be in the same memory location but point to (contain) the address of `string`.

Comment: @tem: You cannot change the location of a variable, only its value, which might be (in the case of pointers) the location of another variable. Always clearly differentiate between pointer and pointee, or other people (and you yourself too!) have to guess what you mean. DWIM is not yet iplemented, and any previous try ended in disaster.

Comment: so, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to point `pointer` at the string addressed by `string`,

```
pointer = string;
```

works.

If you want to point `pointer` at `string`,

```
pointer = &string;
```

is sufficient.

What you actually are doing is casting pointer to `char*`, and assigning through it, which is undefined behavior as `pointer` is `NULL`.
Actually, conversion from `&string` to `char` probably does not work either.

Comment: Thanks, this make sense. I believe I was printing the wrong addresses as well which is what confused me the most.

Comment: Question. In `pointer = string`, isn't specifying simply `string` the pointer to the first index of the string array? I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @beckah: No. Though it decays to that (presuming you meant element and not index), like in most contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply do

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    void *pointer = NULL;
    char *string = "test";
    pointer = &string; // point to the address of string
    printf("The string address: %p\n", string);
    printf("The string: %s\n", string);
    printf("The pointer address: %p\n", pointer);
    printf("The pointer points to: %p\n", (char*)(*(char**)(pointer)));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void *pointer = NULL;
```

`pointer` here is a pointer of type `void`. You need to first make sure that this pointer points to some valid memory location before dereferencing it.

Like

```
pointer = string;
```

PS: Here `string` is a string literal so it is read-only if you try to write to this memory location you might get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a pointer that points to the char pointer `string`, then you should do this:

```
pointer = &string
```

If you want to have a pointer that points to the string "test", then you should do this:

```
pointer = string
```